# Image Hide & Show on Text Hover Using Multiple Images/Links on One Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I've looked around and unfortunately, haven't found anything that quite matches what I'm hoping to achieve. I have two things going on. First an image/content slider which I'm using Awkward Showcase for. Then within each slide I need to build a mousein/mouseout effect that swaps and hides an image when the user hovers over the text option. My JS looks like this:

```
$("#news-2, #news-3, #news-4, #news-5, #news-6").hide();

$("#newsitem-1, #newsitem-2, #newsitem-3, #newsitem-4, #newsitem-5, #newsitem-6").mouseover(function(){

    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');

    if($("#newsitem").val() != $(this).attr('id').replace('newsitem', 'news')){

        $("#news-1").hide();
        $("#news-2").hide();
        $("#news-3").hide();
        $("#news-4").hide();
        $("#news-5").hide();
        $("#news-6").hide();

        $("#newsitem").val($(this).attr('id').replace('newsitem', 'news'));

        var vid = $(this).attr('id').replace('newsitem', 'news');

        $("#" + vid).show();

    }

});
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="showcase" class="showcase">

<div class="showcase-slide cs-1">
  <div class="showcase-content">
    <div class="cs-container">
      <div class="thumbs">
        <div id="news-1"><a href="/link"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/eeeeee/cccccc" border="0"></a></div>
        <div id="news-2" style="display: none;"><a href="/link"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/dddddd/dddddd" border="0"></a></div>
        <div id="news-3" style="display: none;"><a href="/link"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/cccccc/aaaaaa" border="0"></a></div>                 
      </div>

      <div class="cs-links">
        <h2>Link Title 1</h2>
        <ul>
          <li id="newsitem-1"><a href="#">Hover Change Image 1</a></li>
          <li id="newsitem-2"><a href="#">Hover Change Image 2</a></li>
          <li id="newsitem-3"><a href="#">Hover Change Image 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>         
  </div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-caption">Caption Title</div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="showcase-slide cs-2">
  <div class="showcase-content">
    <div class="cs-container">
      <div class="thumbs">
        <div id="news-4"><a href="/link"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/eeeeee/cccccc" border="0"></a></div>
        <div id="news-5" style="display: none;"><a href="/link"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/dddddd/dddddd" border="0"></a></div>
        <div id="news-6" style="display: none;"><a href="/link"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/cccccc/aaaaaa" border="0"></a></div>                 
      </div>

      <div class="cs-links">
        <h2>Link Title 2</h2>
        <ul>
          <li id="newsitem-4"><a href="#">Hover Change Image 1</a></li>
          <li id="newsitem-5"><a href="#">Hover Change Image 2</a></li>
          <li id="newsitem-6"><a href="#">Hover Change Image 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>         
  </div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-caption">Restaurant TV</div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated. One thing to note is the code I've written only works once, once you engage the slide function the hover effect breaks unless you hard refresh.

**Edit**: Question is, how can I make this more efficient. I have multiple items (image and text). And any ideas why this breaks once the slide function is engaged?

I used ID's because it's a one to one relationship between the text and the associated image.

**Edit 2**: If I swap the order of my js, the function breaks. Here is a JSFiddle as long as I keep this order everything works until I engage the slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/mV3dJ/

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere ?

Comment: Just a tip, you can hide multiple elements at once `$("#news-1,#news-2,#news-3,#news-4,#news-5,#news-6").hide();`

Comment: Itay, thank you for the tip!

Comment: which element does `#news-item` id refers to?

Comment: #news-item engages the show/hide behavior, #news contains the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not really seen a function done like this before but one thing that stands out to me as a potential breaker is this

```
var vid = $(this).attr('id').replace('newsitem', 'news');
```

If you're replacing an ID of something which listen to an event, then the event can only occur once on that element (as the next time it has a different name and so won't recognise it.

Ideally you want to use a web debugger like firebug or Chrome developer tools, set breakpoints and figure out from stepping through the code why it isn't working correctly.

Comment: Ben, technically the id doesn't even exist on the page I'm just using it to look for newsitem and news to then replace them on mouse out. I'll admit this a little over my head.

Is there a way to make this work for multiple events? The mousein/mouseout effect works continuously, so long as I don't engage the slide function to move to the next slide container.